# Don't allow camelCase for symfony2 api request

Tags: json, symfony, fosrestbundle

I have a Symfony2 API created using `FOSRestBundle`. I am using:

```
fos_rest:
body_listener:
    array_normalizer: fos_rest.normalizer.camel_keys
```

So that I can submit `JSON` data like this: `my_field` and have them mapped onto my entity's `myField` (on the form builder I use `->add('myField')`).

However if I send `JSON` data as `myField` it treats it the same as `my_field`. Ideally I want that to be turned off, is this possible? (I've tried adding `->add('my_field')` on the form instead, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an issue with FOSRestBundle, but your serializer.  If you're using JMSSerializerBundle you can force identical naming with this in your `parameters.yml`:

```
jms_serializer.camel_case_naming_strategy.class: 
    JMS\Serializer\Naming\IdenticalPropertyNamingStrategy
```